# Does exporting MyISAM table lock when exporting data?

Tags: mysql, export, myisam

I am trying to export a huge MyISAM table in a MySQL database into a .SQL file. Will doing so lock the entire table and prevent applications from using it during the export?

If so, is there an alternative?

Comment: Use mysql yog to export table. Lock is not getting applied but perfomance of mysql get slowed down. But if you use mysql yog OR any other mysql client would be better enough

Comment: Thanks. I am using Sequel Pro.